# Connection strength in a weighted social digraph, based on weights of individual links

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, social-sciences

Given a network where edges represent entities and directed vertices represent relationships between entities, and each vertex has a strength between 0 (no relationship) and 1 (strongest).

I'm looking for a method to calculate the path strength between two entities.

For simple cases, I'm considering the following formulas:

- Path: The strength of the connection is the multiplication of all weights of the links along the path.

[image]

- Parallel direct links: The strength of the connection is *1-(1-w1)(1-w2)...(1-wn)*
  [image]

My questions:

- Were these formulas suggested before?
- How can this method be extended to more complex cases, such as the graphs given below:

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: I don't know where your intuition for those formulas came from, but I recommend the formulas for resistance or capacitance.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: These formulas are similar to resistance formulas, but '+' is replaced with '*', and '/' is replaced with '-'. More important - network resistance formulas are suitable only for non-directed graphs.

Comment: Aren't these just Markov state diagrams?

Comment: @JohnMoeller: The Diagrams are similar, however the sum of weights of all outgoing edges for any given vertex is not bounded. Furthermore, there are no 'moves', and time does not play a role either.

Comment: @LiorKogan : Ah, ok, the sum property is the important difference. In your case, you're saying a node could have a very small relationship with its neighbors (sum < 1) or it could have a very important relationship with its neighbors (sum > 1).